# Can we pass Relative layout objects to OnItemSelectedListener?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-relativelayout, onitemselectedlistener

I have a relative layout object created in an OnCreate method. It works fine, but I want to create a dynamic spinner in `OnItemSelectedListener`.

If I create another variable of relative layout there then it would not render other dynamic control outside `OnItemSelectedListener`.

My code is:

```
RelativeLayout layout;
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MultiQuesRelaLayOut);
final Spinner[] sp = new Spinner[10];
for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    sp[a] = new Spinner(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    para.leftMargin = 300;
    para.topMargin = 100;
    ArrayAdapter < String > spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, value);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp[a].setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    sp[a].setLayoutParams(para);
    sp[a].setTag(a);
    layout.addView(sp[a]);


    sp[a].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1,
        int pos, long arg3) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_questiondynamic);
            String[] DDvalue = GetDropDownvalue(Avalue);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MultiQuesRelaLayOut);
            final Spinner[] Sp = new Spinner[10];
            int add = (int) arg0.getTag();
            Sp[add] = new Spinner(com.example.hakslogin.QuestionActivityDynamic.this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.leftMargin = 25;
            param.topMargin = 200;
            Sp[add].setId(add);
            Sp[add].setLayoutParams(param);
            ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (com.example.hakslogin.QuestionActivityDynamic.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DDvalue);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Sp[add].setAdapter(adapter);
            if (add == 0) {
                layout.addView(Sp[add]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

My dynamic control is creating only issue is relative layout if I create it in an item select event, it does not create reaming dynamic control outside the event.

Can I pass a `RelativeLayout` object in an OnItemSelected event?